# Probability distribution of a set of samples from a normal distribution and a cosine function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

Let $(x_n)_{n=0}^{N}$ be a finite sequence of samples drawn from a normal distribution with mean $0$ and variance $\sigma^2$. I am interested in the distribution of the sequence $$ X_k = \sum_{n=0}^Nx_n \cos(2 \pi k n /N), \quad k = 0,\dots, N$$
Does this sequence also follow a normal distribution? If so, how can it be proved? It would also be helpful if someone can suggest a reference for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. The question from Signal Processing stack exchange  [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24170/what-is-the-statistics-of-the-discrete-fourier-transform-of-white-gaussian-noise) describes this in detail.

The cosine values are deterministic scalars multiplying the $x_n$ so you get a linear combination of Gaussians which is itself a Gaussian.

Answer (score 0):

If $x_n$, $n=0\ldots N$ are independet, then it follows from elementary properties of characteristic functions of random variables:

Let $\varphi_X(t):=\mathbb{E}e^{itX}$ and $\varphi_Y(t):=\mathbb{E}e^{itY}$, where $X,Y$ are independent random variables. Then $\varphi_{aX+bY}(t)=\varphi_X(at)\varphi_Y(bt)$, $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Additionaly, $\varphi_X=\varphi_Y\iff X,Y$ have the same probability distribution.

Also, it follows from the stability.